# how to best create language settings independent excel formula in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, application-settings, regional

I have a macro which creates an excel formula
`range("A2").formula="=TEXT(A1,""YYYYMMDD"")"`
this works well with my US-EN version but gives problem when I try to run it on FR-FR version
I need to adapt the formula to
`range("A2").formula="=TEXT(A1,""AAAAMMJJ"")"`
to have it work correctly on a -FR-FR version but this no longer works on my US-En version.

Any idea about how to manage this?

I have the same kind of issue with the CELL and INFO functions which use a string parameter that is language-dependent but not managed correctly when the formula is created programmatically thru the formula property of the range function.

Is there a property that I can test on and adapt the formula accordingly or better is there a way to have the string parameter automatically translated?

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html

Comment: @Evil Blue Monkey :Thank you for your contribution, but this does not address my issue. I would like to create (with vba) a formula that works on any excel version( whichever the language)

Comment: FYI the code you posted will create a Circular Reference.

Comment: @Chris Neilsen, message modified (to correct circular reference)

Answer (score 3):

You can access the local regional settings via the [`Application.International`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.international) method.  This can then be used to translate your US_EN code to Local settings code.

Something like this

```
Function MakeDateCodeLocal(ByVal Code As String)
    Dim Y As String
    Dim M As String
    Dim D As String
    
    Y = Application.International(xlYearCode)
    M = Application.International(xlMonthCode)
    D = Application.International(xlDayCode)
    ' Add more codes if you need them
    
    Code = Replace$(Code, "Y", Y, , , vbTextCompare)
    Code = Replace$(Code, "M", M, , , vbTextCompare)
    Code = Replace$(Code, "D", D, , , vbTextCompare)
    MakeDateCodeLocal = Code
End Function
```

Then use it like this

```
range("FormulaRange").formula="=TEXT(A1, " & MakeDateCodeLocal("YYYYMMDD") & ")"
```

Comment: I did not know about `International`. Pretty smart and clean. Thumbs up!

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Excuse my late comment: following your reply *"Thanks a lot, This is what I was looking for."* it's not only good use to accept a helpful answer by ticking the green checkmark, but might help other readers to find valuable solutions - above all the answer considered to be the best by yourself as the asking SO participant  :-) @h2so4

Comment: @T.M. Excuse my late reaction, but I did greencheckmark this answer on sep 1'20, together with my "Thanks a lot" reply.

Answer (score 1):

Can't test it properly because I have just one Excel version with spanish language.

As far as I know, you can't have Excel autotranslate the string parameter.

But the `Application` object holds the Language Settings.

```
MsgBox "Install Language - " & _
 Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDInstall) & vbNewLine & _
 "User Interface Language - " & _
 Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI) & vbNewLine & _
 "Help Language - " & _
 Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDHelp)
```

So in your VBA code, check the `msoLanguageIDUI` and depending on the value, use one string parameter or another.

All `msoLanguageIDUI` are listed here:
[MsoLanguageID enumeration (Office)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msolanguageid)

So you could combine this with your needs to choose right formula depending on FR or US-EN:

```
Sub TEST()
Dim LanguageID As Integer
LanguageID = Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)

Range("A1").Formula = CHOOSE_FORMULA(LanguageID)

End Sub


Function CHOOSE_FORMULA(ByVal vLanguage As Integer) As String

Select Case vLanguage
    Case 1033 'The English US language
        CHOOSE_FORMULA = "=TEXT(A1,""YYYYMMDD"")"
    Case 1036 'The French language
        CHOOSE_FORMULA = "=TEXT(A1,""AAAAMMJJ"")"
End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I just tested and it seems that this is not bulletproof. I have a configuration where the vlanguage is 1036, but that still needs YYYYMMDD to work correctly. I am wondering which settings to modify.